# bash fixing noisy data french character

Tags: bash, csv, awk, utf

I have this sample data in my csv:

```
VallÌÎÌãÌ´å©e,100

JoffÌÎÌãÌ´å©,240
```

I think this is because the csv doesn't support utf-8. How would I fix that using bash? I think its a french name.

The things that I have tried so far are using the SED bash to change all french characters to just an alphabet using SED:

```
sed -i 'y/āáǎàēéěèīíǐìōóǒòūúǔùǖǘǚǜĀÁǍÀĒÉĚÈĪÍǏÌŌÓǑÒŪÚǓÙǕǗǙǛ/aaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuuüüüüAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOUUUUÜÜÜÜ/' data.csv
```

but it doesn't work so I'm not too sure how to fix it.

Comment: What are the actual bytes in the file? That doesn't look like UTF-8 either. Please see [the Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](/tags/character-encoding/info) for how to ask a well-defined question or possibly even solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps.

```
iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT Input_file
```

Here is what man page of `iconv` says:

> DESCRIPTION
>          The  iconv  program reads in text in one encoding and outputs the text in another encoding.  If no input files are given, or if it
>   is given as a
>          dash (-), iconv reads from standard input.  If no output file is given, iconv writes to standard output.
>          If no from-encoding is given, the default is derived from the current locale’s character encoding.  If no to-encoding is given, the 
>   default  is
>          derived from the current locale’s character encoding.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't fix it become "VallIIIaI'a(C)e"

Comment: @user3646742, you want to change them to English characters right?